# Changing encryption for HTTP Basic Authentication on Android

Tags: java, android, http, authentication, ssl

I am performing HTTP Basic Authentication in my Android application.  Recently, however, I have been having problems authenticating users due to the following change made on my server:

"...SSL certificates with a key length of 1,024 bits or fewer will be insufficient for security after December 31, 2010. In compliance with these guidelines, most SSL certificate vendors (including GeoTrust) have begun issuing these new 2048-bit keys."

The recommendation was made to update my Java Runtime Environment.  However, seeing as how my application is on the Android, I don't believe that this would do anything.  Therefore, my question is this:

How can I change the following code to use 2048-bit encryption?  Is this possible?  Does anyone have any recommendations?  I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter("Content-type",
        "application/xml");
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(Constants.SERVER_HOST,
                Constants.SERVER_PORT,
                Constants.SERVER_REALM),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username.getText()
                .toString(), password.getText().toString()));

String getURL = Constants.SERVER_URL;
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
responseGet = client.execute(get);
```

Stack trace errors:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException:
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not     found.java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. That code has nothing to do with encryption. The server's administrator is responsible for updating it to use a longer key (2048 bit). You just have to test that your app still works after the update (it seems it doesn't). What exactly is the problem? Can't connect anymore? What error (stack trace) are you getting?

Comment: Hi Nikolay, that's good to know, thanks.  I'm a bit out of my league here. I'm no longer able to authenticate my users, and I have posted the stack trace errors in my original post. As I mentioned above, the server administrators recommended to upgrade the JRE. Another temporary workaround (which would have to be repeated every year) is to manually import the certificate into the truststore...

Comment: The CA that issued their certificate is most probably not trusted by Android. As you cannot import into the system trust store, you'll have to set up a custom trust manager for your HttpClient that trusts the particular CA certificate in addition to the default ones. There are quite a few posts about this on SO. Just don't trust the ones that tell you to accept all certificates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will check out those other posts.